# How to morph a path data to another path data in SVG?

Tags: animation, svg, mathematical-morphology

I'm trying to figure out why it wont morph this path data to another path data, I need to make it look like an real animation.

This is my SMIL code:

```
    <animate xlink:href="#Barra3"  
    repeatCount="indefinite" 
    attributeName="d" 
    dur="5s"
    values="M52,346L56,346C61.523,346 66,350.477 66,356L42,356C42,350.477 46.477,346 52,346Z;
    M54,225C60.627,225 66,230.373 66,237L66,356L42,356L42,237C42,230.373 47.373,225 54,225Z;"/>
```

Here is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/joannesalfa/pen/mdPBJxq
and go line 181. I'm using SMIL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG path animation from lineto to cubic-bezier curve command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222405/svg-path-animation-from-lineto-to-cubic-bezier-curve-command)

Comment: @ccprog it looks helpful answer but it's pretty confusing how it's supposed to divide each C into 3 segments.

Comment: Ah. I see the answer is not universally applicable. This second instruction is specific to that one path; it only applies if you want to morph a `C` intermediate control point into a `L` cordinate. The process of deciding "which point goes where" has no technical answer, but needs to be decided by artistic criteria.

Comment: I still have no idea how to resolve it without artistic criteria, anyway I have no choice but I will use SVGator service, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Ivan could you please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. a simple svg with one simple path showing your problem? Also, are you aware of [not perfect SMIL support](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/5o0yiO440LM/m/59rZqirUQNwJ?pli=1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important when trying to morph a path in svg is thast the d attribute hes to have the same number of commands and the same commands. I've rewritten the short path so that the lines drawing the sides of the shape have a length = 0.

```
M54,346
C60.627,346,66,351.373,66,358
L66,358L42,358L42,358
C42,351.373,47.373,346,54,346Z
```

Please take a look:

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="5 200 100 200" width="100">


  <path d="M54,346
          C60.627,346,66,351.373,66,358
          L66,358L42,358L42,358
          C42,351.373,47.373,346,54,346Z"  stroke="red" fill="gold" >

  <animate  dur='5s'
    attributeType="XML"
    attributeName='d'      
    repeatCount='indefinite'
           values="M54,225
           C60.627,225 66,230.373 66,236
           L66,356L42,356L42,236
           C42,230.373 47.373,225 54,225Z;
                                                                     
           M54,346
           C60.627,346,66,351.373,66,356
           L66,356L42,356L42,356
           C42,351.373,47.373,346,54,346Z;
                                                                                  M54,225
           C60.627,225 66,230.373 66,236
           L66,356L42,356L42,236
           C42,230.373 47.373,225 54,225Z" />
    
    </path>
</svg>
```

#### Update

The OP is commenting:

> Would you mind how to rewrite the short path step by step? I find it's very confusing to me

I'm taking both those paths and I'm breaking them in 5 paths of different colors, one for every command. Please note that I had to add a move to command (M) at the beginning of each path. The value for the move to is the last point of the previous path. The lines, are the blue paths.

For the short path you can see those blue paths in the code but not in the svg because their length is 0. I needed those 0 length lines because you have lines in the long path.

```css
svg{width:200px;border:solid;overflow:visible; fill:none}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="40 220 28 140" >
  <desc>The short path</desc>
  <path d="M54,346 C60.627,346,66,351.373,66,356" stroke="red" /> 
  <path d="M66,356 L66,356" stroke="blue" />           
  <path d="M66,356 L42,356" stroke="green" />    
  <path d="M42,356 L42,356" stroke="blue" /> 
  <path d="M42,356 C42,351.373,47.373,346,54,346" stroke="gold"/>

</svg>

<svg viewBox="40 220 28 140" >
  <desc>The long path</desc>
      <path d="M54,225 C60.627,225 66,230.373 66,237" stroke="red"/> 
      <path d="M66,237 L66,356" stroke="blue" />
      <path d="M66,356 L42,356" stroke="green" />  
      <path d="M42,356 L42,237" stroke="blue"/>
      <path d="M42,237 C42,230.373 47.373,225 54,225;" stroke="gold"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Would you mind how to rewrite the short path step by step? I find it's very confusing to me.