# Interpolate between SVG path data in canvas with vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, canvas

I'm getting into animating paths from svgs via canvas and I didn't find any find a solution to my problem.

So, I was wondering if there was a way to interpolate between two paths with canvas with vanilla JS.

Say for example I got the following two paths (below, data from two separate svgs with same amount of points). I would like to render this on a html canvas and then animate the `pathFrom` to the `pathTo`. The issue is that I can't find a way to interpolate a canvas `Path2d` from one path to another. I know there are ways to do this with d3 and greensock (as far as I understood). However, I was wondering if there was a way to do this in vanilla JS? I'm using a `requestAnimationFrame` and I can draw out the shapes. However, most of the animation tutorials goes into animating position, but not morphing between paths. Any good resources for how svg paths is working are also appreciated.

```
const pathFrom =
'M23.7352 0.369841C85.3189 7.71421 80.6777 113.03 133.57 145.567C195.165 183.458 311.403 127.501 339.251 194.464C366.052 258.909 240.961 295.135 223.934 362.853C204.583 439.815 303.932 550.052 238.617 594.698C172.291 640.035 94.9536 536.792 23.7352 499.699C-12.1565 481.005 -35.5832 445.949 -73.5848 432.093C-137.534 408.775 -220.095 440.701 -268.841 393.016C-322.234 340.785 -366.735 246.849 -328.889 182.347C-288.726 113.898 -177.168 153.198 -106.827 116.898C-53.7497 89.5061 -35.5165 -6.69643 23.7352 0.369841Z';
const pathTo =
'M333.702 9.09439C400.207 -18.9688 481.701 22.56 535.832 70.3843C587.84 116.332 599.327 189.936 615.006 257.623C629.325 319.434 641.091 382.628 622.193 443.189C603.157 504.195 570.832 572.637 510.369 592.96C450.645 613.034 396.085 531.384 333.702 540.154C251.775 551.672 190.489 686.242 116.944 648.269C48.6306 612.998 127.263 497.365 106.957 423.081C88.3135 354.876 -27.4193 304.788 6.03235 242.523C42.3358 174.95 163.85 245.476 226.262 201.015C287.413 157.451 264.557 38.2718 333.702 9.09439Z';
```

How would one approach this in an ES6 vanilla way with using a `new Path2d(path)` (or however you would approach it)?

I'm hoping for some fun discussions and thoughts!

Comment: A simpler way to morph the path would be using SMIL animations. Olease take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696504/how-to-morph-a-path-data-to-another-path-data-in-svg/63705181#63705181

Comment: That is definitely one way to do it @enxaneta. I am still looking for a way to work with canvas though, since there might be other thing I would like to use, on top of the svg paths.
I could just change the path and have a transition on css as well :)